# I can't type \ in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

First of all, I am trying to bind `\ t` to start quickOpen.

I have the following key shortcuts:

```
    {
        "key": "\\ t",
        "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen"
    },
```

Now when I press `\`, I see:

`(\) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...`

This prevents me from actually typing `\` in my code

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Remove the key shortcut. Using an unmodified key (without Ctrl or Alt) as a keyboard shortcut never works, because of the exact reasons you're experiencing here - programs using that shortcut have no way of telling that's not what you're trying to do. Use something else to start quickOpen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who come across this question,

This is the answer:

```
{
    "key": "\\ t",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen",
    "when": "vim.mode != 'Insert'",
},
```